# Character theory and Quantum Chemistry

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ho.history-overview, characters, mathematical-chemistry

Who (presumably a chemist) realized first the efficiency of character theory in calculations of orbitals of atoms? In which year?

Comment: These posts on [hsm.se] seems to be - to some extent - related:[History of group theory character tables (as used in physics and chemistry)](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7568) and [How did group theory enter quantum mechanics?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/170)

Comment: There is tension between the title about chemistry ([molecular orbitals](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory)) and body about spectroscopy ([atomic orbitals](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital)). Carlo answers about the former, but the same Scholz paper says that applications of *representation theory* to atomic orbitals started earlier in Wigner ([1927](//zbmath.org/?q=an:53.0855.01|53.0856.01)), von Neumann-Wigner ([1928](//zbmath.org/?q=an:54.0976.05)). If you insist on use of *characters* then Bethe ([1929](//zbmath.org/?q=an:55.0546.06); in gallica) has a lot more.

Answer (score 8):

[Introducing groups into quantum theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086005001072), by Erhard Scholz (2006):

> In quantum chemistry, representations of permutation groups made their
>   first appearance about the same time as they did in spectroscopy. The
>   topic was opened up by a joint publication [1] of two young physicists, 
>   Walter  Heitler  and  Fritz  London,  who  had  come  to  Zürich  on 
>   Rockefeller  grants  in  1926, respectively 1927, to work with E.
>   Schrödinger. Group theoretic methods were
>   first applied in two papers by W. Heitler [2,3].
>
> [1] Heitler, W., London,  F.  *Wechselwirkung 
>   neutraler  Atome  und  homöpolare  Bindung  nach  der 
>   Quanten-mechanik.* Zeitschrift für Physik **44**, 455–472 (1927).
>   [2] Heitler, W., *Zur Gruppentheorie der homöopolaren chemischen
>   Bindung.* Zeitschrift für Physik **47**, 835–858 (1928).
>   [3] Heitler, W., *Zur
>   Gruppentheorie der Wechselwirkung von Atomen.* Zeitschrift für Physik
>   **51**, 805–816 (1928).

Answer (score 5):

I think this realization is an immediate consequence of that of the efficiency of group theory in the quantum theory of angular momentum.
The early culprits for the Gruppenpest are Weyl in his 1931 book "Gruppentheorie und quantenmechanik"
and B. van der Waerden in his 1932 book "Die gruppentheoretische Methode in der Quantenmechanik". You can probably also find a discussion of this in the more recent book by Biedenharn and Louck.